fix error handler in al futter project for a webiste
I'm making an error handler class for my project, for now, it should handle every exception possible on the sign-in or the sign-up page, now I'm working on the sign-in page.
every time I try to test the error handler I get an exception but not the correct one
for example, I get
An unknown error occurred.

or
Exception: Failed to sign in: [firebase_auth/invalid-credential] The supplied auth credential is incorrect, malformed or has expired.

instead it should be:

invalid email, invalid password, wrong password or email, ext...

here is my error handler code:
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class AppErrorHandler {
  final String errorCode;
  final String errorMessage;

  // Constructor
  AppErrorHandler(this.errorCode, this.errorMessage);

  // Factory method to map FirebaseAuthException to custom errors
  factory AppErrorHandler.fromFirebaseError(FirebaseAuthException error) {
    // Mapping Firebase error codes to user-friendly messages
    final errorMap = {
      'invalid-email': 'Invalid email address.',
      'user-not-found': 'No account found with this email.',
      'wrong-password': 'Incorrect password.',
      'too-many-requests': 'Too many requests. Please try again later.',
      'email-already-in-use': 'The email address is already in use by another account.',
      'user-disabled': 'User account has been disabled.',
      'invalid-phone-number': 'Invalid phone number.',
      'weak-password': 'Password is too weak.',
    };

    // Fallback error code and message if no match is found
    final defaultError = 'An unknown error occurred: ${error.message}';
    final errorDetail = errorMap[error.code] ?? defaultError;

    return AppErrorHandler(error.code, errorDetail);
  }

  // Method to get an HTTP-like status code based on the error code
  int getHttpStatus() {
    final statusMap = {
      'invalid-email': 400,
      'user-not-found': 404,
      'wrong-password': 401,
      'too-many-requests': 429,
      'email-already-in-use': 409,
      'user-disabled': 403,
      'weak-password': 400,
      'invalid-phone-number': 400,
    };

    return statusMap[errorCode] ?? 500; // Default to 500 (internal server error)
  }

  // Override toString() for better logging/debugging output
  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'AppErrorHandler(code: $errorCode, message: $errorMessage, status: ${getHttpStatus()})';
  }

  // Static method for handling general FirebaseAuth exceptions
  static String handleAuthError(FirebaseAuthException e) {
    final errorMap = {
      'invalid-email': 'The email address is not valid.',
      'user-disabled': 'The user has been disabled.',
      'user-not-found': 'No user found with this email.',
      'wrong-password': 'Wrong password provided.',
      'email-already-in-use': 'The email address is already in use.',
      'operation-not-allowed': 'This operation is not allowed.',
      'weak-password': 'The password is too weak.',
    };

    // Return user-friendly error message or a default one
    return errorMap[e.code] ?? 'An unknown error occurred.';
  }

  // General error handler for unexpected exceptions
  static String handleGeneralError(Exception e) {
    if (e is FirebaseAuthException) {
      return handleAuthError(e);
    } else {
      return 'An unexpected error occurred.';
    }
  }

  // Method to handle sign-in-specific errors
  static String handleSignInError(Exception e) {
    return handleGeneralError(e);
  }


}

and here is how I call the error handler methods in the sign up class
void _signIn() async {
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      String email = _emailController.text;
      String password = _passwordController.text;

      try {
        await _authService.signIn(email: email, password: password);
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const HomePageScreen()),
        );
      } catch (e) {
        
        //print(e.toString());
        String errorMessage =
            AppErrorHandler.handleGeneralError(e as Exception); 
            _showErrorDialog(errorMessage);
      }
    }
  }

  static String handleGeneralError(Exception e) {
    if (e is FirebaseAuthException) {
      return handleAuthError(e);
    } else {
      return 'An unexpected error occurred.';
    }
  }

I get a pop up error with this note (with every trial to test the error handler class)
An unexpected error occurred.

but when I call the method like this :
static String handleGeneralError(Exception e) {
     return handleAuthError(e as FirebaseAuthException);
  }

I get this error
DartError: TypeError: Instance of '_Exception': type '_Exception' is not a subtype of type 'FirebaseAuthException'

dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 288:3  throw_
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_shared/lib/rti.dart 1405:3                         _failedAsCheck
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_shared/lib/rti.dart 1383:3                         _generalAsCheckImplementation
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_shared/lib/rti.dart 1278:30                        _installSpecializedAsCheck
packages/group_changing_app/src/utils/error_handler.dart 71:31               handleGeneralError
packages/group_changing_app/src/ui/sign_in_screen.dart 64:29                 <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 610:19          <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 634:23          <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 585:5           <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1681:54                                         runBinary
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 219:22                                   handleError
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 914:46                                   handleError
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 935:13                                   _propagateToListeners
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 715:5                                    [_completeError]
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 503:7           completeError
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 569:12          _asyncRethrow
packages/group_changing_app/src/services/auth_service.dart 75:3              <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 610:19          <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 634:23          <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 585:5           <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1681:54                                         runBinary
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 219:22                                   handleError
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 914:46                                   handleError
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 935:13                                   _propagateToListeners
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 715:5                                    [_completeError]
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 503:7           completeError
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 569:12          _asyncRethrow
packages/firebase_auth/src/firebase_auth.dart 606:3                          <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 610:19          <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 634:23          <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 585:5           <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1681:54                                         runBinary
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 219:22                                   handleError
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 914:46                                   handleError
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 935:13                                   _propagateToListeners
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 715:5                                    [_completeError]
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 503:7           completeError
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 569:12          _asyncRethrow
packages/firebase_auth_web/firebase_auth_web.dart 454:34                     <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 610:19          <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 634:23          <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 585:5           <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1681:54                                         runBinary
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 219:22                                   handleError
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 914:46                                   handleError
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 935:13                                   _propagateToListeners
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 715:5                                    [_completeError]
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 801:7                                    callback
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11                             _microtaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5                              _startMicrotaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 186:7  

